# recently stored data cannot be read by another method

Tags: c#, database, ms-access

I have added the data as:

```
public static void insert()
{
    try
    {
        string connStr =
                (@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=G:\test.accdb;Persist Security Info=False");
        OleDbConnection conn1 = new OleDbConnection();
        conn1.ConnectionString = connStr;
        OleDbCommand cmd = conn1.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandText =
                "INSERT INTO patientinfo (medicareNo, title, fName, lName, gender, height, weight, age )" +
                " VALUES(" + p.getMedicare() + ",'" + p.getTitle() + "','" + p.getfName() + "','" + p.getlName() +
                "','" + p.getGender() + "'," + p.getheight() + "," + p.getweight() + "," + p.getAge() + ");";

        conn1.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        //displayResult(medicareNo);
    }
    catch (OleDbException exp)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error");
    } 
    displayResult(medicareNo);
}
```

and I have another method for reading data

```
public static void displayResult(int medicareNo )
{
    try
    {
        string connStr =
                (@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=G:\test.accdb;Persist Security Info=False");
        OleDbConnection conn1 = new OleDbConnection();
        conn1.ConnectionString = connStr;
        OleDbCommand cmd1 = conn1.CreateCommand();

        cmd1.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM patientinfo WHERE medicareNo = " + "" + medicareNo + "";
        conn1.Open();

        OleDbDataReader rdr = null;
        rdr = cmd1.ExecuteReader();

        if (rdr.HasRows)
        {
            checkvalue = true;
            foreach (DataRow row in rdr.GetSchemaTable().Rows)
            {
                Console.Write(row["ColumnName"].ToString() + " ");
            }
            Console.WriteLine(" ");
            while (rdr.Read())
            {
                Console.Write(rdr["medicareNo"].ToString());
                Console.Write(" ");
                Console.Write(rdr["title"].ToString());
                Console.Write(" ");
                Console.Write(rdr["fName"].ToString());
                Console.Write(" ");
                Console.Write(rdr["lName"].ToString());
                Console.Write(" ");
                Console.Write(rdr["gender"].ToString());
                Console.Write(" ");
                Console.Write(rdr["height"].ToString());
                Console.Write(" ");
                Console.Write(rdr["weight"].ToString());
                Console.Write(" ");
                Console.WriteLine(rdr["age"].ToString());
                Console.WriteLine(".......................");
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Patient registered. Information retrieved. ");
        }
        else
        {
            checkvalue = false;
            Console.WriteLine("Patient not registered. Add Patient information for registration.");
        }
    }
    catch (OleDbException exp)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("error.");
    }
}
```

The problem is displayResult() cannot find the recently added data, so i cannot display it right after adding it. Even calling them separately in main() didnt work. It just goes to "patient not registered..................".Any suggestions please

update: get set method for medicareno.

```
public void SetMedicare(int pMedicare)
{
    if (pMedicare > 0)
    {
        medicareNo = pMedicare;
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Medicare Number not valid");
    }
}
public int getMedicare()
{
    return medicareNo;
}
```

Comment: Can you confirm the insert worked?

Comment: Where is `medicareNo` (the `int` value) assigned or passed into the `insert` method? Post the code for `p.getMedicare()`.

Comment: yes. It worked. the data is stored in database. thanks

Comment: medicareNo is a class variable, getting the value from here.

Comment: try changing your select statement to: `"SELECT * FROM patientinfo WHERE medicareNo = " + medicareNo;`

Comment: public void SetMedicare(int pMedicare)
            {
               if (pMedicare > 0)
                {
                medicareNo = pMedicare;
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Medicare Number not valid");
            }
        }
        public int getMedicare()
        {
            return medicareNo;
        }

Comment: @muratgu, tried. didnt work

Comment: why don't you use the same connection? just pass `conn1` to displayResult as a parameter and call `displayResult` right after `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery`.

Answer (score 0):

Your SELECT statement is the issue:

```
"SELECT * FROM patientinfo WHERE medicareNo = " + "" + medicareNo + ""
```

It is comparing `medicareNo` as a string, instead of as an `int`.

Change your query to this:

```
"SELECT * FROM patientinfo WHERE medicareNo = " + medicareNo
```

Comment: both are equal, OP not using statement like `medicareNo = '"+ medicareNo + "'"`, then it will take as string

Answer (score 0):

change `displayResult(medicareNo);` with below

```
displayResult(p.getMedicare());
```

And also I would change your methods as below

```
    public static void insert()
    {
        try
        {
            string connStr = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=G:\test.accdb;Persist Security Info=False";
            string commandText = "INSERT INTO patientinfo (medicareNo, title, fName, lName, gender, height, weight, age )" +
                                " VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

            using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(connStr))
            using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(commandText, con))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@medicareNo", p.getMedicare());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@title", p.getTitle());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fName", p.getfName());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lName", p.getlName());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gender", p.getGender());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@height", p.getheight());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@weight", p.getweight());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@age", p.getAge());
                con.Open();
                int ret = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                if(ret ==1)
                    Console.WriteLine("Insert Successful");
            }

            displayResult(p.getMedicare());
        }
        catch (OleDbException exp)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error");
        }

    }

    public static void displayResult(int medicareNo)
    {
        try
        {
            string connStr = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=G:\test.accdb;Persist Security Info=False";
            string commandText = "SELECT * FROM patientinfo WHERE medicareNo = ?";
            using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(connStr))
            using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(commandText, con))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@medicareNo", medicareNo);
                con.Open();
                using (OleDbDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    if (rdr.HasRows)
                    {
                        foreach (DataRow row in rdr.GetSchemaTable().Rows)
                        {
                            Console.Write(row["ColumnName"].ToString() + " ");
                        }
                        Console.WriteLine(" ");
                        while (rdr.Read())
                        {
                            string str = string.Format("{0} {1} {2} {3} {4} {5} {6} {7}", 
                                rdr["medicareNo"], rdr["title"], rdr["fName"], rdr["lName"],
                                rdr["gender"], rdr["height"], rdr["weight"], rdr["age"]);

                            Console.WriteLine(str);
                        }
                        Console.WriteLine("Patient registered. Information retrieved. ");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Patient not registered. Add Patient information for registration.");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (OleDbException exp)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("error.");
        }
    }
```